# One Problem Regarding Permutation

Tags: permutations, inclusion-exclusion, permutation-cycles

Let $A$ be the set of all permutations $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_6$
of $1, 2, \dots, 6$ such that $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ is not a
permutation of $1, 2, \dots, k$ for any $k$ , $1\leq k \leq 5$.
Then the number of elements in $A$ is $528$.

Can anyone please help me by giving any hint. I have no idea how to start.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: A few comments on rigour: a permutation of a set $A$ is not a listing of its elements, but a bijection from $A$ to $A$, hence should be expressed as such. Furthermore, the very informal and unpleasant spirit of employing $...$ should be renounced. If I understood correctly you meant to say: let $A$ be the set of all $\sigma \in \Sigma_6$ such that for no $k$ with $1 \leqslant k \leqslant 5$ do we have $\sigma([1, k]) \subseteq [1, k]$.

Comment: Exactly that's what I want. @ΑΘΩ

Comment: I am not getting any idea to start.@BMath

Comment: @sani: well, you could approach things manually, count those permutations that do stabilize each interval $[1, k]$ and apply the inclusion-exclusion principle. I am not sure whether a neat statement can be made in the general case, though. As a hint, the number of permutations of degree $n$ that stabilize a subset of cardinal $k$ is $k!(n-k!)$.

Comment: I was trying in this manner. But it is getting too complicated..@ΑΘΩ

Comment: Look up http://oeis.org/A003319, if I understand the question

Comment: That was very easy...Very Good Suggestion..Thank You.@Empy2

Answer (score 0):

Consider the ordered sums $k_1+\cdots+k_m=6$ and the permutations that permute the first $k_1$, the next $k_2$ etc. elements among themselves. Every permutation is associated with exactly one of these sums, and you want to count the ones that are associated with the trivial sum $6=6$. We can partially order the sums by saying that $s_1\lt s_2$ if $s_1$ arises from $s_2$ by combining summands. This partial order corresponds to the partial order of the subsets of the five $+$ operators in $1+1+1+1+1+1$ by inclusion.

The [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Special_elements) for this poset yields a coefficient $+1$ for every sum with an odd number of summands and $-1$ for every sum with an even number of summands (corresponding to the standard Möbius function for subsets ordered by inclusion). Now, for each unordered partition of $6$, find the number of ordered sums that correspond to it and the number of permutations that correspond to each of those sums, and add up the products with the corresponding signs, yielding (in the order $6$, $5+1$, $4+2$, $3+3$, $4+1+1$, $3+2+1$, $3+1+1+1$, $2+2+2$, $2+2+1+1$, $2+1+1+1+1$, $1+1+1+1+1+1$):

$$
1\cdot6!-2\cdot5!-2\cdot4!\cdot2!-1\cdot3!\cdot3!+3\cdot4!+6\cdot3!\cdot2!-4\cdot3!+1\cdot2!^3-6\cdot2!^2+5\cdot2!-1=461\;.
$$

This agrees with the number in the OEIS sequence and doesn't agree with yours, so it seems that either your problem statement or your result is wrong.

Comment: hII @joriki I could not understand your solution. I have applied brute force ..Can you please check my try?

Comment: @sani: Unfortunately I don't understand yours either :-) See my comment there. Is there anything in particular that you don't understand in my answer, or is inclusion–exclusion as a whole not part of your toolset?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this problem in Brute-force method..
Basically I need to find the number of elements in $A$ which is the set of all $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that for no $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq 5$ do we have $\phi([1,k]) \subset [1,k]$.

**Case 1:**  Let's Find out the number of $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that $\phi([1,5]) \subset [1,5]$.

Here $[1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5]$ denotes the set of all permutations of the elements $1 , 2, 3, 4 ,5$. We will get $5!$ such permutations.

**Case 2:**  Let's Find out the number of $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that $\phi([1,4]) \subset [1,4]$ and do not belong to case 1.
$[1 , 2, 3, 4] (5 \,6)$ are such elements . Here $[1 , 2, 3, 4]$ denotes the set of all permutations of the elements $1 , 2, 3, 4$.
We will get $4!$ such permutations.

**Case 3:**    Let's Find out the number of $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that $\phi([1,3]) \subset [1,3]$ and do not belong to case 1 and case 2.
$[ 1, 2, 3] (4 \, 5 \, 6)$  , $[ 1 , 2 , 3] (4 \, 6 \, 5)$  , $[ 1 , 2 , 3] (4 \, 6)$  are such elements.
So total number of such elements is $3! .3 = 18$

**Case 4:**    Let's Find out the number of $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that $\phi([1,2]) \subset [1,2]$ and do not belong to case 1 and case 2 and case 3.

$[ 1 , 2] (3 \, 6) (4 \, 5)$ ,$[ 1 , 2] (3 \,  6) [4]  [5]$ , $[ 1 , 2] ( 3 \, 4 \, 6)$ , $[ 1 , 2] (3 \, 6 \, 4)$ , $[ 1 , 2] (3 \, 5 \, 6)$ , $[ 1 , 2] (3 \, 6\, 5)$  , $[ 1 , 2] ( 3 \, 5) (4 \, 6)$ , $[ 1 ,2] ( 3 \, 4 \, 5 \,6)$

We will get total $ 2 . 6 + 2 + 2.3!=26 $

**Case 5:**
Let's Find out the number of $\phi \in \sum_6$ such that $\phi(1 )= 1$ and do not belong to case 1 and case 2 , case 3 , case 4.

$[1] (2 \, 3 \, 4 \,  5 \, 6)$ -- We will have 4! such cases.

$[1] (2  \, 3 \, 5 \, 6)$ ----We will have $3!$ such cases.

$[1] (2 \, 3 \, 4 \, 6)$ ----We will have $3!$ such cases.

$[1] (2 \,  4 \, 5 \, 6)$ ----We will have $3!$ such cases.

$[1] [3,4] (2 \, 5 \, 6)$ ----We will have $12$ such cases.

$[1] [3 , 4,5] (2  \, 6)$ ----We will have $3!$ such cases.

$[1] (2 \, 5) ( 3 \, 6)$

$[1] (2 \, 4) ( 3 \, 6)$

$[1] (2  \, 5) ( 4 \, 6)$

$[1] (2  \, 4) ( 3 \, 5 \, 6)$ ----We will have $2$ such cases.

$[1] (2 \, 5) ( 3 \, 4 \, 6)$ ----We will have $2$ such cases.

$[1] (4 \, 6) ( 2 \, 3 \, 5)$ ----We will have $2$ such cases.

$[1] (3 \, 6) ( 2 \, 4 \, 5)$ ----We will have $2$ such cases.

So we are getting 259 total elements which are to be excluded from the set of all permutations of $1 , 2 , 3, 4 ,5 ,6$.

So the number of elements in $A$ is $(720 - 259) = 461$.

Can anyone please check my solution if I miss out any cases or any repetition.

Thank You in advance..

Comment: Since the result is known from OEIS to be incorrect, I think this should be part of the question rather than an answer. Also, you should define your notation. You're using curly braces, square brackets, round parentheses with commas and round parentheses without commas, but you've only introduced one of these four notations.

Comment: Okk I am editing my answer.. I am really not understanding your answer..@joriki

Comment: OK, I see you no longer use curly braces, and except for one comma that you seem to have overlooked in $(5,6)$, you no longer use parentheses with commas. I gather that the parentheses without commas are meant to be standard cycle notation?

Comment: In case $4$, I don't see why you count $6$ of the cases twice and $1$ only once. Also you seem to be missing the $2\cdot3!$ cases of the form $[1,2](3 4 5 6)$. In case $5$ I don't understand why you count $12$ cases for $[1](2 5 6)$ and $3!$ cases for $[1](2 6)$. Also, you're counting $[1](3456)$ in case $5$, which doesn't belong there, since it should have been counted (twice) in case $4$. All in all, the many errors underline why it's more reliable to use inclusion–exclusion than brute force.

Comment: Exactly ... Without commas are meant to be Standard Cyclic notation.

Comment: And I am replying your other comment..Just give me few minutes to recheck. @joriki

Comment: For Case 4:  I have considered $[1 , 2]$ as a permutation...So for each case $( 1 \, 2)$ and $[1]$ , $[2]$ have to be considered. So we will have 6.2 =12 cases for 6 cases and you are right that will not be 1 for the same reason ..I am editing it. I am replying for the other cases in few minutes.@joriki

Comment: I have edited the case 4 as per your suggestion.Please have a  look.@joriki

Comment: Why the count of permutations like $[1] ( 2 5 6)$ is 12? Actually this has to be written like $[1] [3,4] ( 2 5 6)$..You can have $[1] ( 2 5 6)$ , $[1] ( 2 3 6)$ , $[1] ( 2 4 6)$ , and for each of the three cases we will get 4 cases..@joriki

Comment: Hii@joriki I  have edited  according to your suggestion...Can you please have a look..

Comment: In case $5$ you're missing $4$ cases from $[1](235)(46)$ and $[1](245)(36)$; if you include them the result comes out right. (By the way, I used inclusion–exclusion to pinpoint that $4$ cases were missing in case $5$ – so even if you want to check a brute force solution, it pays off to learn about inclusion–exclusion :-).

Comment: Thank You..I will try to understand your solution..However if you elaborate little more it would be little easier for me to understand...@joriki

Comment: I can elaborate, but I'd need to know at what level to start. What do you know about inclusion–exclusion?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the minimum eligibility to be able to understand that? I know set theory , Real Analysis , Basic Topolgy... Will I be able to understand  this theorem? I want to learn that extensively. If you could suggest me a link it would be wonderful..@joriki

Comment: You can read about the basic inclusion–exclusion principle [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). I used a generalized form of this principle, Möbius inversion on posets, which is described [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#On_posets); that section also provides a reference to Section $3.7$ of Vol. $1$ of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* (which is anyway a good reference for these things); this is p. $303$ of [this online PDF of the book](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf).

Comment: You don't really need the generalized form in this case, though – as I mentioned, you can regard it as standard inclusion–exclusion on the subsets of the five $+$ operators in the ordered sums.

Comment: Thank You Very Much...I will see that link...Thank you for investing so much time for my question...@joriki